# Need to find child node value between two specific child nodes

Tags: xml, xslt-1.0

I have the following XML.

```
    <LogHeader>
      <LogProcess>
        <LogTestStep>
          <LogTestStepID>16048116</LogTestStepID>
          <TestStepID>627520</TestStepID>
          <Status>passed</Status>
          <LogProcess>
            <LogProcessID>905364</LogProcessID>
            <ProcessID>18861</ProcessID>
            <ProcessName>SAP Login</ProcessName>
            <Status>passed</Status>
            <LogTestStep>
              <LogTestStepID>16048117</LogTestStepID>
              <TestStepID>628189</TestStepID>
              <Status>passed</Status>
              <ApplicationVersionName>System - 1.0</ApplicationVersionName>
              <ObjectName>Execution</ObjectName>
              <ActionName>Comment</ActionName>
              <Narrative>Step Begins</Narrative>
            </LogTestStep>
            <LogTestStep>
              <LogTestStepID>16048118</LogTestStepID>
              <TestStepID>627642</TestStepID>
              <Status>passed</Status>
              <ApplicationVersionName>System - 1.0</ApplicationVersionName>
              <ObjectName>Execution</ObjectName>
              <ActionName>Comment</ActionName>
              <Narrative>"Verify if SAP Screen is opened and login screen is displayed"</Narrative>
            </LogTestStep>
            <LogTestStep>
              <LogTestStepID>16048119</LogTestStepID>
              <TestStepID>627643</TestStepID>
              <Status>passed</Status>
              <ApplicationVersionName>System - 1.0</ApplicationVersionName>
              <ObjectName>Execution</ObjectName>
              <ActionName>Comment</ActionName>
              <Narrative>"SAP Screen should be opened and login screen is displayed"</Narrative>
            </LogTestStep>
            <LogTestStep>
              <LogTestStepID>16048120</LogTestStepID>
              <TestStepID>627644</TestStepID>
              <Status>passed</Status>
              <ApplicationVersionName>System - 1.0</ApplicationVersionName>
              <ObjectName>Execution</ObjectName>
              <ActionName>Comment</ActionName>
              <Narrative>"SAP Screen is opened and login screen is displayed"</Narrative>
            </LogTestStep>
            <LogTestStep>
              <LogTestStepID>16048121</LogTestStepID>
              <TestStepID>627645</TestStepID>
              <Status>passed</Status>
              <ApplicationVersionName>System - 1.0</ApplicationVersionName>
              <ObjectName>Execution</ObjectName>
              <ActionName>Comment</ActionName>
              <Narrative>"SAP Screen is not opened because of wrong credentials"</Narrative>
            </LogTestStep>
            <LogTestStep>
              <LogTestStepID>16048122</LogTestStepID>
              <TestStepID>627647</TestStepID>
              <Status>passed</Status>
              <ApplicationVersionName>SAP Core - 1.0</ApplicationVersionName>
              <ObjectName>SAP Main</ObjectName>
              <ActionName>Launch SAP</ActionName>
              <Narrative>Launch SAP "MARS EJ2:QA" "EJ2" as "643019183 ".</Narrative>
            </LogTestStep>
            <LogTestStep>
              <LogTestStepID>16048124</LogTestStepID>
              <TestStepID>627648</TestStepID>
              <Status>passed</Status>
              <ApplicationVersionName>System - 1.0</ApplicationVersionName>
              <ObjectName>Operating System</ObjectName>
              <ActionName>Capture Screen Image</ActionName>
              <Narrative>Capture Current Screen</Narrative>
              <Image>
                <Path>D:\Ramanesh VB Script\26Jul\Input1.jpg</Path>
              </Image>
            </LogTestStep>
            <LogTestStep>
              <LogTestStepID>16048124</LogTestStepID>
              <TestStepID>627648</TestStepID>
              <Status>passed</Status>
              <ApplicationVersionName>System - 1.0</ApplicationVersionName>
              <ObjectName>Operating System</ObjectName>
              <ActionName>Capture Screen Image</ActionName>
              <Narrative>Capture Current Screen</Narrative>
              <Image>
                <Path>D:\Ramanesh VB Script\26Jul\Input1.jpg</Path>
              </Image>
            </LogTestStep>
            <LogTestStep>
              <LogTestStepID>16048125</LogTestStepID>
              <TestStepID>628190</TestStepID>
              <Status>passed</Status>
              <ApplicationVersionName>System - 1.0</ApplicationVersionName>
              <ObjectName>Execution</ObjectName>
              <ActionName>Comment</ActionName>
              <Narrative>Step Ends</Narrative>
            </LogTestStep>
          </LogProcess>
        </LogTestStep>
        <LogTestStep>
          <LogTestStepID>16048126</LogTestStepID>
          <TestStepID>627521</TestStepID>
          <Status>passed</Status>
          <LogProcess>
            <LogProcessID>905365</LogProcessID>
            <ProcessID>18860</ProcessID>
            <ProcessName>Create Order</ProcessName>
            <Status>passed</Status>
            <LogTestStep>
              <LogTestStepID>16048127</LogTestStepID>
              <TestStepID>628274</TestStepID>
              <Status>passed</Status>
              <ApplicationVersionName>System - 1.0</ApplicationVersionName>
              <ObjectName>Execution</ObjectName>
              <ActionName>Comment</ActionName>
              <Narrative>Step Begins</Narrative>
            </LogTestStep>
            <LogTestStep>
              <LogTestStepID>16048128</LogTestStepID>
              <TestStepID>627529</TestStepID>
              <Status>passed</Status>
              <ApplicationVersionName>System - 1.0</ApplicationVersionName>
              <ObjectName>Execution</ObjectName>
              <ActionName>Comment</ActionName>
              <Narrative>"Verify if a Tcode VA01 is inputed "</Narrative>
            </LogTestStep>
            <LogTestStep>
              <LogTestStepID>16048129</LogTestStepID>
              <TestStepID>627530</TestStepID>
              <Status>passed</Status>
              <ApplicationVersionName>System - 1.0</ApplicationVersionName>
              <ObjectName>Execution</ObjectName>
              <ActionName>Comment</ActionName>
              <Narrative>"Tcode VA01 should be inputed "</Narrative>
              <ExecutionStatus>ContinueExecution</ExecutionStatus>
            </LogTestStep>
            <LogTestStep>
              <LogTestStepID>16048130</LogTestStepID>
              <TestStepID>627531</TestStepID>
              <Status>passed</Status>
              <ApplicationVersionName>System - 1.0</ApplicationVersionName>
              <ObjectName>Execution</ObjectName>
              <ActionName>Comment</ActionName>
              <Narrative>"Tcode VA01 is inputed "</Narrative>
            </LogTestStep>
            <LogTestStep>
              <LogTestStepID>16048131</LogTestStepID>
              <TestStepID>627532</TestStepID>
              <Status>passed</Status>
              <ApplicationVersionName>System - 1.0</ApplicationVersionName>
              <ObjectName>Execution</ObjectName>
              <ActionName>Comment</ActionName>
              <Narrative>"Tcode VA01 not inputed "</Narrative>
            </LogTestStep>
            <LogTestStep>
              <LogTestStepID>16048132</LogTestStepID>
              <TestStepID>627534</TestStepID>
              <Status>passed</Status>
              <ApplicationVersionName>SAP Core - 1.0</ApplicationVersionName>
              <ObjectName>okcd</ObjectName>
              <ActionName>[Input]</ActionName>
              <Narrative>Enter "VA01" into the Ok Code field.</Narrative>
            </LogTestStep>
            <LogTestStep>
              <LogTestStepID>16048133</LogTestStepID>
              <TestStepID>628275</TestStepID>
              <Status>passed</Status>
              <ApplicationVersionName>System - 1.0</ApplicationVersionName>
              <ObjectName>Execution</ObjectName>
              <ActionName>Comment</ActionName>
              <Narrative>Step Ends</Narrative>
            </LogTestStep>
            <LogTestStep>
              <LogTestStepID>16048134</LogTestStepID>
              <TestStepID>628276</TestStepID>
              <Status>passed</Status>
              <ApplicationVersionName>System - 1.0</ApplicationVersionName>
              <ObjectName>Execution</ObjectName>
              <ActionName>Comment</ActionName>
              <Narrative>Step Begins</Narrative>
            </LogTestStep>
            <LogTestStep>
              <LogTestStepID>16048135</LogTestStepID>
              <TestStepID>627535</TestStepID>
              <Status>passed</Status>
              <ApplicationVersionName>System - 1.0</ApplicationVersionName>
              <ObjectName>Execution</ObjectName>
              <ActionName>Comment</ActionName>
              <Narrative>"Verify if value Order Type is inputed to Order Type text field"</Narrative>
            </LogTestStep>
            <LogTestStep>
              <LogTestStepID>16048136</LogTestStepID>
              <TestStepID>627536</TestStepID>
              <Status>passed</Status>
              <ApplicationVersionName>System - 1.0</ApplicationVersionName>
              <ObjectName>Execution</ObjectName>
              <ActionName>Comment</ActionName>
              <Narrative>" Order Type should be inputed to Order Type text field"</Narrative>
            </LogTestStep>
            <LogTestStep>
              <LogTestStepID>16048137</LogTestStepID>
              <TestStepID>627537</TestStepID>
              <Status>passed</Status>
              <ApplicationVersionName>System - 1.0</ApplicationVersionName>
              <ObjectName>Execution</ObjectName>
              <ActionName>Comment</ActionName>
              <Narrative>" Order Type is inputed to Order Type text field"</Narrative>
            </LogTestStep>
            <LogTestStep>
              <LogTestStepID>16048138</LogTestStepID>
              <TestStepID>627538</TestStepID>
              <Status>passed</Status>
              <ApplicationVersionName>System - 1.0</ApplicationVersionName>
              <ObjectName>Execution</ObjectName>
              <ActionName>Comment</ActionName>
              <Narrative>" Order Type is not  inputed to Order Type text field"</Narrative>
            </LogTestStep>
            <LogTestStep>
              <LogTestStepID>16048139</LogTestStepID>
              <TestStepID>627540</TestStepID>
              <Status>passed</Status>
              <ApplicationVersionName>SAP Core - 1.0</ApplicationVersionName>
              <ObjectName>(VBAK-AUART) Order Type</ObjectName>
              <ActionName>[Input]</ActionName>
              <Narrative>Input "OR" into the (VBAK-AUART) Order Type CTextField.</Narrative>
            </LogTestStep>
            <LogTestStep>
              <LogTestStepID>16048140</LogTestStepID>
              <TestStepID>627546</TestStepID>
              <Status>passed</Status>
              <ApplicationVersionName>SAP Core - 1.0</ApplicationVersionName>
              <ObjectName>(VBAK-VKORG) Sales Organization</ObjectName>
              <ActionName>[Input]</ActionName>
              <Narrative>Input "NZ10" into the (VBAK-VKORG) Sales Organization CTextField.</Narrative>
            </LogTestStep>
            <LogTestStep>
              <LogTestStepID>16048141</LogTestStepID>
              <TestStepID>627552</TestStepID>
              <Status>passed</Status>
              <ApplicationVersionName>SAP Core - 1.0</ApplicationVersionName>
              <ObjectName>Distribution Channel</ObjectName>
              <ActionName>[Input]</ActionName>
              <Narrative>Input "01" into the Distribution Channel CTextField.</Narrative>
            </LogTestStep>
            <LogTestStep>
              <LogTestStepID>16048142</LogTestStepID>
              <TestStepID>627558</TestStepID>
              <Status>passed</Status>
              <ApplicationVersionName>SAP Core - 1.0</ApplicationVersionName>
              <ObjectName>Division</ObjectName>
              <ActionName>[Input]</ActionName>
              <Narrative>Input "01" into the Division CTextField.</Narrative>
            </LogTestStep>
            <LogTestStep>
              <LogTestStepID>16048143</LogTestStepID>
              <TestStepID>627559</TestStepID>
              <Status>passed</Status>
              <ApplicationVersionName>System - 1.0</ApplicationVersionName>
              <ObjectName>Operating System</ObjectName>
              <ActionName>Capture Screen Image</ActionName>
              <Narrative>Capture Current Screen</Narrative>
              <Image>
                <Path>D:\Ramanesh VB Script\26Jul\Input2.jpg</Path>
              </Image>
            </LogTestStep>
            <LogTestStep>
              <LogTestStepID>16048144</LogTestStepID>
              <TestStepID>628277</TestStepID>
              <Status>passed</Status>
              <ApplicationVersionName>System - 1.0</ApplicationVersionName>
              <ObjectName>Execution</ObjectName>
              <ActionName>Comment</ActionName>
              <Narrative>Step Ends</Narrative>
            </LogTestStep>
            <LogTestStep>
              <LogTestStepID>16048145</LogTestStepID>
              <TestStepID>628306</TestStepID>
              <Status>passed</Status>
              <ApplicationVersionName>System - 1.0</ApplicationVersionName>
              <ObjectName>Execution</ObjectName>
              <ActionName>Comment</ActionName>
              <Narrative>Step Begins</Narrative>
            </LogTestStep>
            <LogTestStep>
              <LogTestStepID>16048146</LogTestStepID>
              <TestStepID>627560</TestStepID>
              <Status>passed</Status>
              <ApplicationVersionName>System - 1.0</ApplicationVersionName>
              <ObjectName>Execution</ObjectName>
              <ActionName>Comment</ActionName>
              <Narrative>"Verify if ENTER is pressed"</Narrative>
            </LogTestStep>
            <LogTestStep>
              <LogTestStepID>16048147</LogTestStepID>
              <TestStepID>627561</TestStepID>
              <Status>passed</Status>
              <ApplicationVersionName>System - 1.0</ApplicationVersionName>
              <ObjectName>Execution</ObjectName>
              <ActionName>Comment</ActionName>
              <Narrative>"ENTER should be  pressed"</Narrative>
            </LogTestStep>
            <LogTestStep>
              <LogTestStepID>16048148</LogTestStepID>
              <TestStepID>627562</TestStepID>
              <Status>passed</Status>
              <ApplicationVersionName>System - 1.0</ApplicationVersionName>
              <ObjectName>Execution</ObjectName>
              <ActionName>Comment</ActionName>
              <Narrative>"ENTER  is pressed"</Narrative>
            </LogTestStep>
            <LogTestStep>
              <LogTestStepID>16048149</LogTestStepID>
              <TestStepID>627563</TestStepID>
              <Status>passed</Status>
              <ApplicationVersionName>System - 1.0</ApplicationVersionName>
              <ObjectName>Execution</ObjectName>
              <ActionName>Comment</ActionName>
              <Narrative>"ENTER not pressed"</Narrative>
            </LogTestStep>
            <LogTestStep>
              <LogTestStepID>16048150</LogTestStepID>
              <TestStepID>627565</TestStepID>
              <Status>passed</Status>
              <ApplicationVersionName>SAP Core - 1.0</ApplicationVersionName>
              <ObjectName>Enter</ObjectName>
              <ActionName>[Press]</ActionName>
              <Narrative>Press the Enter Button.</Narrative>
            </LogTestStep>
            <LogTestStep>
              <LogTestStepID>16048151</LogTestStepID>
              <TestStepID>628307</TestStepID>
              <Status>passed</Status>
              <ApplicationVersionName>System - 1.0</ApplicationVersionName>
              <ObjectName>Execution</ObjectName>
              <ActionName>Comment</ActionName>
              <Narrative>Step Ends</Narrative>
            </LogTestStep>
            <LogTestStep>
              <LogTestStepID>16048152</LogTestStepID>
              <TestStepID>628308</TestStepID>
              <Status>passed</Status>
              <ApplicationVersionName>System - 1.0</ApplicationVersionName>
              <ObjectName>Execution</ObjectName>
              <ActionName>Comment</ActionName>
              <Narrative>Step Begins</Narrative>
            </LogTestStep>
            <LogTestStep>
              <LogTestStepID>16048153</LogTestStepID>
              <TestStepID>627566</TestStepID>
              <Status>passed</Status>
              <ApplicationVersionName>System - 1.0</ApplicationVersionName>
              <ObjectName>Execution</ObjectName>
              <ActionName>Comment</ActionName>
              <Narrative>"Verify if value Account  is inputed to Sold To Party text field"</Narrative>
            </LogTestStep>
            <LogTestStep>
              <LogTestStepID>16048154</LogTestStepID>
              <TestStepID>627567</TestStepID>
              <Status>passed</Status>
              <ApplicationVersionName>System - 1.0</ApplicationVersionName>
              <ObjectName>Execution</ObjectName>
              <ActionName>Comment</ActionName>
              <Narrative>"A value Account should be inputed to Sold To Party text field"</Narrative>
            </LogTestStep>
            <LogTestStep>
              <LogTestStepID>16048155</LogTestStepID>
              <TestStepID>627568</TestStepID>
              <Status>passed</Status>
              <ApplicationVersionName>System - 1.0</ApplicationVersionName>
              <ObjectName>Execution</ObjectName>
              <ActionName>Comment</ActionName>
              <Narrative>"A value Account  is inputed to Sold To Party text field"</Narrative>
            </LogTestStep>
            <LogTestStep>
              <LogTestStepID>16048156</LogTestStepID>
              <TestStepID>627569</TestStepID>
              <Status>passed</Status>
              <ApplicationVersionName>System - 1.0</ApplicationVersionName>
              <ObjectName>Execution</ObjectName>
              <ActionName>Comment</ActionName>
              <Narrative>"A value Account not inputed to Sold To Party text field"</Narrative>
            </LogTestStep>
            <LogTestStep>
              <LogTestStepID>16048157</LogTestStepID>
              <TestStepID>627571</TestStepID>
              <Status>passed</Status>
              <ApplicationVersionName>SAP Core - 1.0</ApplicationVersionName>
              <ObjectName>Sold-to party</ObjectName>
              <ActionName>[Input]</ActionName>
              <Narrative>Input "1019821" into the Sold-to party CTextField.</Narrative>
            </LogTestStep>
            <LogTestStep>
              <LogTestStepID>16048158</LogTestStepID>
              <TestStepID>627577</TestStepID>
              <Status>passed</Status>
              <ApplicationVersionName>SAP Core - 1.0</ApplicationVersionName>
              <ObjectName>Ship-to party</ObjectName>
              <ActionName>[Input]</ActionName>
              <Narrative>Input "1019821" into the Ship-to party CTextField.</Narrative>
            </LogTestStep>
            <LogTestStep>
              <LogTestStepID>16048159</LogTestStepID>
              <TestStepID>627578</TestStepID>
              <Status>passed</Status>
              <ApplicationVersionName>System - 1.0</ApplicationVersionName>
              <ObjectName>Text</ObjectName>
              <ActionName>Concatenate</ActionName>
              <Narrative>Initialize T[PONumber] to "031801"</Narrative>
            </LogTestStep>
            <LogTestStep>
              <LogTestStepID>16048160</LogTestStepID>
              <TestStepID>627584</TestStepID>
              <Status>passed</Status>
              <ApplicationVersionName>SAP Core - 1.0</ApplicationVersionName>
              <ObjectName>PO Number</ObjectName>
              <ActionName>[Input]</ActionName>
              <Narrative>Input "031802" into the PO Number TextField.</Narrative>
            </LogTestStep>
            <LogTestStep>
              <LogTestStepID>16048162</LogTestStepID>
              <TestStepID>627590</TestStepID>
              <Status>passed</Status>
              <ApplicationVersionName>SAP Core - 1.0</ApplicationVersionName>
              <ObjectName>All items</ObjectName>
              <ActionName>[Input Cell]</ActionName>
              <Narrative>Input "0020397"' into row "1" of the "Material" column.</Narrative>
            </LogTestStep>
            <LogTestStep>
              <LogTestStepID>16048163</LogTestStepID>
              <TestStepID>627596</TestStepID>
              <Status>passed</Status>
              <ApplicationVersionName>SAP Core - 1.0</ApplicationVersionName>
              <ObjectName>All items</ObjectName>
              <ActionName>[Input Cell]</ActionName>
              <Narrative>Input "1"' into row "1" of the "Order Quantity" column.</Narrative>
            </LogTestStep>
            <LogTestStep>
              <LogTestStepID>16048164</LogTestStepID>
              <TestStepID>627597</TestStepID>
              <Status>passed</Status>
              <ApplicationVersionName>System - 1.0</ApplicationVersionName>
              <ObjectName>Operating System</ObjectName>
              <ActionName>Capture Screen Image</ActionName>
              <Narrative>Capture Current Screen</Narrative>
              <Image>
                <Path>D:\Ramanesh VB Script\26Jul\Input3.jpg</Path>
              </Image>
            </LogTestStep>
            <LogTestStep>
              <LogTestStepID>16048165</LogTestStepID>
              <TestStepID>628314</TestStepID>
              <Status>passed</Status>
              <ApplicationVersionName>System - 1.0</ApplicationVersionName>
              <ObjectName>Execution</ObjectName>
              <ActionName>Comment</ActionName>
              <Narrative>Step Ends</Narrative>
            </LogTestStep>
          </LogProcess>
        </LogTestStep>
      </LogProcess>
    </LogHeader>
```

Each `LogHeader/LogProcess/LogTestStep` has one `LogProcess` which has one or more blocks of `LogTestStep`. The blocks are identified using `Narrative` node value. Each block starts with `Step Begins` and ends with `Step Ends` value of `Narrative` element.

From each block I need to find whether `ActionName` node has `Capture Screen Image` value. If present then XSL should print `Yes` otherwise `No`.

I tried with the following XSL but not working.

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
    <xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
      <xsl:output method="html" />
      <xsl:template match="LogHeader">
        <html>
          <head>
          </head>
          <body>
            <div class="container">
              <BR></BR>
              <xsl:for-each select="//LogTestStep[Narrative='Step Begins']">
                <xsl:if test="Narrative = 'Step Begins'">
                  <BR/>
                  <table cellSpacing="1" cellPadding="1" align="center" border="1">
                    <thead>
                      <th>Step ID</th>
                      <th>Test Case Name</th>
                      <th>Step Description</th>
                      <th>Expected Result</th>
                      <th>Actual Result</th>
                      <th>Status</th>
                      <th>Evidence?</th>
                    </thead>
                    <tbody>
                      <tr>
                        <xsl:if test="Status = 'passed'">
                          <td style="color:green;" width="10%">
                            <xsl:value-of select="position()" />
                          </td>
                          <td style="color:green;" width="10%">
                            <!--<xsl:value-of select="//LogProcess/ProcessName"/>-->
                            <xsl:value-of select="../ProcessName"/>
                          </td>
                          <td style="color:green;" width="20%">
                            <xsl:value-of select="following-sibling::LogTestStep[1]/Narrative"/>
                          </td>
                          <td style="color:green;" width="20%">
                            <xsl:value-of
                            select="following-sibling::LogTestStep[2]/Narrative"/>
                          </td>
                          <td style="color:green;" width="20%">
                            <xsl:value-of
                            select="following-sibling::LogTestStep[3]/Narrative"/>
                          </td>
                          <td style="color:green;font-weight: bold;" width="10%">
                            <xsl:value-of select="Status"/>
                          </td>
                          <xsl:if test="following-sibling::LogTestStep[6]/ActionName = 'Capture Screen Image'">
                            <td style="color:green;" width="10%">
                              Yes
                            </td>
                          </xsl:if>
                          <xsl:if test="following-sibling::LogTestStep[6]/ActionName != 'Capture Screen Image'">
                            <td style="color:green;" width="10%">
                              No
                            </td>
                          </xsl:if>
                        </xsl:if>
                      </tr>
                    </tbody>
                  </table>
                  <BR/>
                </xsl:if>
                <xsl:if test="ActionName = 'Capture Screen Image'">
                  <br/>
                  <div align="center">
                    <xsl:for-each select="Image">
                      <p>
                        <xsl:element name="img">
                          <xsl:attribute name="src">
                            <xsl:value-of select="Path"/>
                          </xsl:attribute>
                        </xsl:element>
                      </p>
                    </xsl:for-each>
                  </div>
                  <br/>
                  <br/>
                </xsl:if>
              </xsl:for-each>
            </div>
          </body>
        </html>
      </xsl:template>
    </xsl:stylesheet>
```

If more than one Narrative blocks ('Step Begins' and 'Step Ends') available, then the result is not proper.

Expected Output:

[Image Output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Gwi8M.jpg)

Under "Evidence?" column the resule "Yes" or "No" should printed based on Narrative condition.

Comment: Could you please edit the question and add the expected output?

Comment: Added Expected Output. Please click the link to view the expected output (screenshot)

Answer (score 0):

The same code i try to run and getting the proper output:

```html
<html>
   <head>
      <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
   </head>
   <body>
      <div class="container"><BR><BR><table cellSpacing="1" cellPadding="1" align="center" border="1">
            <thead>
               <th>Step ID</th>
               <th>Test Case Name</th>
               <th>Step Description</th>
               <th>Expected Result</th>
               <th>Actual Result</th>
               <th>Status</th>
               <th>Evidence?</th>
            </thead>
            <tbody>
               <tr>
                  <td style="color:green;" width="10%">1</td>
                  <td style="color:green;" width="10%">SAP Login</td>
                  <td style="color:green;" width="20%">"Verify if SAP Screen is opened and login screen is displayed"</td>
                  <td style="color:green;" width="20%">"SAP Screen should be opened and login screen is displayed"</td>
                  <td style="color:green;" width="20%">"SAP Screen is opened and login screen is displayed"</td>
                  <td style="color:green;font-weight: bold;" width="10%">passed</td>
                  <td style="color:green;" width="10%">
                     Yes
                     
                  </td>
               </tr>
            </tbody>
         </table><BR><BR><table cellSpacing="1" cellPadding="1" align="center" border="1">
            <thead>
               <th>Step ID</th>
               <th>Test Case Name</th>
               <th>Step Description</th>
               <th>Expected Result</th>
               <th>Actual Result</th>
               <th>Status</th>
               <th>Evidence?</th>
            </thead>
            <tbody>
               <tr>
                  <td style="color:green;" width="10%">2</td>
                  <td style="color:green;" width="10%">Create Order</td>
                  <td style="color:green;" width="20%">"Verify if a Tcode VA01 is inputed "</td>
                  <td style="color:green;" width="20%">"Tcode VA01 should be inputed "</td>
                  <td style="color:green;" width="20%">"Tcode VA01 is inputed "</td>
                  <td style="color:green;font-weight: bold;" width="10%">passed</td>
                  <td style="color:green;" width="10%">
                     No
                     
                  </td>
               </tr>
            </tbody>
         </table><BR><BR><table cellSpacing="1" cellPadding="1" align="center" border="1">
            <thead>
               <th>Step ID</th>
               <th>Test Case Name</th>
               <th>Step Description</th>
               <th>Expected Result</th>
               <th>Actual Result</th>
               <th>Status</th>
               <th>Evidence?</th>
            </thead>
            <tbody>
               <tr>
                  <td style="color:green;" width="10%">3</td>
                  <td style="color:green;" width="10%">Create Order</td>
                  <td style="color:green;" width="20%">"Verify if value Order Type is inputed to Order Type text field"</td>
                  <td style="color:green;" width="20%">" Order Type should be inputed to Order Type text field"</td>
                  <td style="color:green;" width="20%">" Order Type is inputed to Order Type text field"</td>
                  <td style="color:green;font-weight: bold;" width="10%">passed</td>
                  <td style="color:green;" width="10%">
                     No
                     
                  </td>
               </tr>
            </tbody>
         </table><BR><BR><table cellSpacing="1" cellPadding="1" align="center" border="1">
            <thead>
               <th>Step ID</th>
               <th>Test Case Name</th>
               <th>Step Description</th>
               <th>Expected Result</th>
               <th>Actual Result</th>
               <th>Status</th>
               <th>Evidence?</th>
            </thead>
            <tbody>
               <tr>
                  <td style="color:green;" width="10%">4</td>
                  <td style="color:green;" width="10%">Create Order</td>
                  <td style="color:green;" width="20%">"Verify if ENTER is pressed"</td>
                  <td style="color:green;" width="20%">"ENTER should be  pressed"</td>
                  <td style="color:green;" width="20%">"ENTER  is pressed"</td>
                  <td style="color:green;font-weight: bold;" width="10%">passed</td>
                  <td style="color:green;" width="10%">
                     No
                     
                  </td>
               </tr>
            </tbody>
         </table><BR><BR><table cellSpacing="1" cellPadding="1" align="center" border="1">
            <thead>
               <th>Step ID</th>
               <th>Test Case Name</th>
               <th>Step Description</th>
               <th>Expected Result</th>
               <th>Actual Result</th>
               <th>Status</th>
               <th>Evidence?</th>
            </thead>
            <tbody>
               <tr>
                  <td style="color:green;" width="10%">5</td>
                  <td style="color:green;" width="10%">Create Order</td>
                  <td style="color:green;" width="20%">"Verify if value Account  is inputed to Sold To Party text field"</td>
                  <td style="color:green;" width="20%">"A value Account should be inputed to Sold To Party text field"</td>
                  <td style="color:green;" width="20%">"A value Account  is inputed to Sold To Party text field"</td>
                  <td style="color:green;font-weight: bold;" width="10%">passed</td>
                  <td style="color:green;" width="10%">
                     No
                     
                  </td>
               </tr>
            </tbody>
         </table><BR></div>
   </body>
</html>
```

Comment: If the steps has Narrative "Capture Current Screen" then "Evidence?" value is "Yes" otherwise "No".
In this case, Steps 3 and 5 should be "Yes".

Comment: No! on the 6th following-sibling::LogTestStep[6]/ActionName are [input] and we are checking for yes if value is = Capture Screen Image. Then it is no as per the condition.

Comment: I Agree. But my question is how to confirm the node with Narrative "Capture Current Screen" is available between the nodes "Step Begins" and "Step Ends".
The above mentioned code (following-sibling::LogTestStep[6]/ActionName) I tried for testing only.